# Menu that appears from the bottom on button click Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I am learning Android these days, and I am having some trouble implementing something. When I click on the image icon, I want a menu to appear from below. The screenshot is as below. (Sorry it's in chinese....)

[image]

Comment: Post code/show what you have done so far.

Comment: well, I don't know how I should implement this. I am not looking for someone to write the code for me, just some guide. Is it supposed to a menu or something?

Answer (score 1):

There's awesome library on [github](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) to get your task done.

All you need to do is setup your layout in two part as describe in below code
part 1: Your main activity(main frame)

part 2: bottom Panel which will be shown when user swipe/click on button.
You must check how to set "**anchor point true**" in library document.

```
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoParalaxOffset="10dp">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!--This is bottom layout.-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="#0000FF"
                android:text="Button 1" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="#0000FF"
                android:text="Button 1" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="#0000FF"
                android:text="Button 1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do here is to replicate the action sheet of iOS in android. There is this library which does exactly what you are looking for, [https://github.com/baoyongzhang/android-ActionSheet](http://action-sheet) . You can either have it as it as it is provided by author or you can clone it and suit your need accordingly. I would prefer if you could clone it as a module in your app that way you have limitless way to re-design it. If you need help on that let us know

Answer (score 0):

You can simply follow the below link , it will implement what u need :
http://trickyandroid.com/fragments-translate-animation/

This will be done through Transition Fragment Animation .